# How to install PyCairo 1.10 on Mac OSX with default python

Tags: python, pycairo

Has anyone installed pycairo 1.10 on the mac using the new waf build? Its failing on can't find python headers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think waf is seriously broken for Mac OS X :(

Here's how it worked for me. After `python waf configure` failed to find Python.h, I looked through the **config.log** file located in **build_directory** and found out that the true cause of failure was incompatible architecture. The waf script tries to build a simple source file with CPython calls in it using i386 architecture. It fails to do so, because my python is built for the x86_64 architecture.

I guess, you could rebuild python as a universal binary, I haven't tried that. It is possible, however, to build pycairo using the x86_64 architecture. Here's how.

---

My setup:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.2

$ type python
python is /usr/local/bin/python

$ file /usr/local/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64

$ brew --version
0.8
```

***Importrant: my python version is built for the `x86_64` architecture. Make sure it is also the case for you before performing the steps described below.***

***brew stands for [homebrew](https://brew.sh/). You must use it instead of fink or MacPorts in order for the following steps to work for you.***

---

Now, to install cairo and pycairo I do the following:

1. `brew install cairo` (version **1.10.2** as of today)
2. Get pycairo source for python 2.x (if you get a snapshot, it is named **py2cairo**, whereas **pycairo** now requires python 3.x). I used the source from **master** branch (commit f3435910d8f5365b45ebd4216f4043383c9e3e19)
3. Open `wscript` in your editor of choice, locate the line `env = ctx.env` in the function `configure` and add the following line below it

   `env.append_unique('CFLAGS', ['-arch', 'x86_64'])`
4. Save the file
5. Run these commands in your terminal:

   `export CC=/usr/bin/gcc`

   `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/cairo/1.10.2/lib/pkgconfig/`

   ***Important: the latter path will only work for you if you installed cairo via homebrew***
6. Then run the waf commands described in the pycairo's INSTALL file:

   `python waf configure`

   `python waf build`

   `python waf install`

This should do it. If it doesn't work for you, I think it's better to raise the topic on the pycairo mailing list (if it has one).

Comment: Haha I tried this as I wanted to check out brew and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Minor nitpick - you're not actually using the default python?

Comment: @jabley default python is too old. Version 2.7 added lots of useful little things — http://www.python.org/getit/releases/2.7/

Comment: I had to follow some additional steps to properly set LD_LIBRARY_PATH and a few other env vars, via instructions here: http://www.niconomicon.net/blog/2011/10/09/2120.wrestling.python.snow.leopard

Comment: I followed these steps but got the error `Cairo pkgconfig requires xcb-shm package which is not installed`. I changed the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/cairo/<VERSION>/lib/pkgconfig/:/opt/X11/lib/pkgconfig` and the configure step worked. Source: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/14123

Answer (score 12):

For anyone coming back to this, I was able to get py2cairo installed on OSX Lion with a slightly different approach, based on llimllib's link. Hope this helps:

```
python waf clean
export PYTHONPATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LINKFLAGS='-search_dylibs_first  -L /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/'
export ARCHFLAGS='-arch x86_64'
export CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/cairo/1.10.2/lib/pkgconfig/

python waf configure --prefix=$PYTHONPATH
python waf build
python waf install
```

Comment: Worked for me using the Mac Ports cairo library, just didn't set the pkg_config_path the above flags where enough

Comment: Worked for me without the CC or PKG_CONFIG_PATH flags.

Answer (score 3):

android's step almost works.
one needs to use (from llimllib):

`export ARCHFLAGS='-arch x86_64'`

in step 5, and then `python waf install` can succeed.