# Cannot Install py2cairo on Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, waf

I am trying to install py2cairo on a framework build (Mac OSX Lion) of python 2.7.3 using brew.  I have been unsuccessful this far.

First, I tried a simple

```
brew install py2cairo
```

This seems to work only on a non-framework build of python.  When I do this on my framework build python faults as soon as I import cairo with an incompatible binary error.

Second, I have tried to build it myself by grabbing it from github and issuing:

```
python waf configure
```

This fails with:

```
Checking for library python2.7           : not found 
Checking for library python2.7           : not found 
Checking for library python2.7           : not found 
Checking for library python27            : not found 
Checking for program python2.7-config    : /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/bin/python2.7-   config 
Checking for header Python.h             : Could not find the python development headers 
The configuration failed
(complete log in /Users/tobin/tmp/py2cairo/build_directory/config.log)
```

I have tried everything at: [How to install PyCairo 1.10 on Mac OSX with default python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6886578/how-to-install-pycairo-1-10-on-mac-osx-with-default-python) but none of this has helped.

It appears to me that this may be failing to find python2.7 library and header file since it is a framework build.  Is that possible?  I was looking at the brew formula and it appears that framework builds do not get --enable-share set at build time.  I'm not sure if that is relevant here - but maybe one possibility.

Anyone other insights would be great.  Thanks in advance.

### UPDATE:

I discovered that the inability to build py2cairo had to do with the use of the "-march=native" flag by gcc.  gcc (4.2.1) on Mac OSX has issues with this. I then reinstalled gcc as well as python. Afterwards when building py2cairo with waf - it was getting "-march=core2" and everything built.

Unfortunately, not all is good yet.  I get the same error when I import cairo from my build that I got from the brew version (as mentioned above).  The exact error message is:

```
>>> import cairo
Fatal Python error: Interpreter not initialized (version mismatch?)
Abort trap: 6
```

and then python exits.

It would now seem that the issue is related to the framework build of python. I tested it without a framework build and it worked fine.

Comment: It looks like framework builds are shared builds after all.  I checked the python27 library and it is a Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64.

Comment: For the record, there are at least three different kinds of Python builds on OS X:  non-shared, shared, and framework (an OS X only kind of shared).  You might want to take a look at the MacPorts portfile for py27-cairo (http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=py27-cairo).  MacPorts is often better at dealing with complex ports with many dependencies.

Comment: I just discovered that waf is getting CFLAGS from python's distutils and the flag "-march=native" is being used.  It appears that the apple installed version of gcc does not work with this.  At least on my machine it does not - I verified this by attempting to compile a very simple file with it.  Still not clear yet where I can control this - or otherwise unset it altogether.

Answer (score 1):

So as to not leave this question dangling ... I wanted to follow up with my resolution and learning points:

1. As noted above there was an incompatibility with my version of OSX and a gcc compile flag called -march=native.  In a later version it was coming up as -march=core2.  This pretty much fixed itself with compiler/version changes after cleaning up my machine.
2. For years I have had quite a mess with all of my various MAC OSX installs - and accepting the "migration option".  Two machines ago - I installed the python binaries for versions 2.4, and 2.5,  Then eventually went to macports for various reasons.  Then eventually went to homebrew.  When I went to homebrew I tried to clean things up by hand (but of course this can be challenging).  To make matters worse - everytime I have gotten a new mac (2 times) in the last 6 years I take "the migration install" option and this pushes the mess forward and makes it worse.  So as I started looking into things further - I had various installs of python, with different versions - mac-native, python-native, mac ports, homebrew, and probably even others too on my system. So my best guess is that cairo was somehow finding one of these and trying to build against it.

I finally solved this by deleting a bunch of old python installs by hand and then starting over with a fresh virtualenv and homebrew install of python 2.7.

WARNING:  I don't think that this is the smartest way to go.  I was careful not to delete a version of Python that I thought came native with OSX Lion (I think it is 2.6) - but it is not clear how it may potentially effect some other things that may have depended on older mac installs of python. I ended up deleting a 2.3, a 2.4, and two different 2.5s - along with various links in some places.  WHAT A MESS!  Unless you are absolutely sure of what it is you are doing (which I was not) I would not suggest this approach.  I was basically trying to kill 6 years of python install crud that has collected.

To be safe I probably should have started with a fresh OSX Lion install and then added my homebrew version and went from there.  I will likely do this in the near future.