# install python cairo on OS X

Tags: python, macos, pycairo

I want to run [some library](https://github.com/CodeReclaimers/neat-python) which uses cairocffi package.

However, when I try to run it I get:

```
OSError: dlopen() failed to load a library: cairo / cairo-2 /
```

So I've installed cairo using 'brew install cairo'.
Then I tried to install py2cairo (1.10.0), (using waf) and got

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Looking for this error in google gives a lot of pages but regarding Xcode. Finally I found [this](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=37414) (later also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11191411/installing-cairo-on-os-x-lion). I was then able to install py2cairo using './waf install'.

But I still had the same error, so I went to the cairocffi/**init**.py and changed line 46 from:

```
cairo = dlopen(ffi, 'cairo', 'cairo-2')
```

to:

```
cairo = dlopen(ffi, 'cairo', 'cairo-2', 'py2cairo')
```

error changed only to:

```
OSError: dlopen() failed to load a library: cairo / cairo-2 / py2cairo
```

I can't see if it was installed properly, but probably not, because I don't see it using

```
sorted(["%s==%s" % (i.key, i.version) for i in pip.get_installed_distributions()])
```

which I can understand since I installed it without pip. But I also can't import it in python console either with 'import cairo' or 'import py2cairo'.

I tried 'brew install cairo' and got 'cairo-1.14-0 already installed'. I tried to install py2cairo-1.10.0, can it be the source of problems?

I use Python 2.7.3 and have OS X 10.10.5.

Comment: Looking at the [Homebrew package list](http://braumeister.org/search/cairo), it looks you probably also need `brew install py2cairo` to get the Python bindings; `brew install cairo` only gets the underlying graphics library. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes, Homebrew told me it is already installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but reinstalling python helped.
I updated it to 2.7.11 and the whole process went smoothly.